# Problem with DataGridView - wont update with my data

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hej i am sending a sql command using SqlDataReader.
I am getting 1 row back, which i am turning into my own created object, where i have overwritten tostring, so i know for sure that it has been returned. (Console.Writeline(arrayList[0].toString());
But still when i try updating the dataGridView1 with the arraylist as a datasource it doesnt do anything.

```
private void buttonUpdaterGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource=Regnskab.getInstance().dbSelectFromTo(dateTimePickerFraDato.Text, dateTimePickerTilDato.Text);
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
```

So i am hoping someone can give me a little hint, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the columns up with the DataPropertyNames set as your object's properties?

Comment: What does the getInstance return and what controls its lifetime?

Comment: Pieter >> No your right i havnt, last time i did it, it wasnt nessecary though.. ill read up on that and comeback too ya.

Comment: Marco>> getInstance(), if you dont know the "singleton pattern", i think you should read up on it. Since its a very usable pattern imo.
Basicaly, its a way to ensure that you only have 1 instance of the object, so if you create it in your main file, then all the files next to it can still use the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what i did wrong...
It couldnt, as Pieter suggested figure out the columns, this was because i had forgotten to make get methods in the dataclass...
After get methods was created, datagridview did it all nicely

Answer (score 0):

`.Update()` is used to execute the UpdateCommand.

If you're trying to refresh what is displayed in the GridView, try using `.DataBind()` instead. If you're trying to update the data in your object, you have to specify what method is associated with `.Update()`.

Comment: Isnt it only in .net that you use Databind() ?
I defently dont have access to it in my windows forms atm.